# How do I find a complete GPG fingerprint when verifying a signature?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, gpg4win

When I right-click a signature file and click More GpgEX Options -> Verify, it says it's valid, showing my email address and last 8 hex digits of my fingerprint. Doing Right-click then GPGshell -> "Decrypt.../Verify/Import" gives the same. If I wanted to verify this for real I'd want all 40 hex digits. How can I view all 40 digits of someone's fingerprint when verifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it in a terminal (command prompt):

`gpg --fingerprint <user_id>`

And from gpg's manual page:

```
  --fingerprint
          List all keys (or the specified ones) along with  their  finger‐
          prints.  This  is  the  same  output as --list-keys but with the
          additional output of a line with the fingerprint.  May  also  be
          combined  with  --list-sigs or --check-sigs.  If this command is
          given twice, the fingerprints of all secondary keys  are  listed
          too.
```